# Use the_title_attribute() for the WHERE parameter in a page template

Tags: page-template

**Goal**:  Create a page template that queries that database based on page title.  This allows for "dynamic" pages based off of the title.

I've got the page template set up and working when I hard code the id, when I try and use the_title_attribute() it's not working.  This is what I'm attempting.

```
$id = the_title_attribute();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <databasename>.<tablename> WHERE name = '". $id."'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

The issue with this is that the_title_attribtue() doesn't populate in time for my query because it's populating later for the page to be rendered.  So I'm trying to figure out how to pull page title so I can use it in SQL select statements to generate content for my page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `get_the_title()` with `$wpdb->prepare()`?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I attempted to use prepare based on examples I saw but the same result happens, at the time of execution it returns blank.  $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM <databasename>.<tablename> WHERE name = '%d'", get_the_title());

Comment: Have you turned on debugging? And `%d` looks for a decimal or number value, you need to use `%s`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks, updating the code to use '%s' along with the prepare statement provided the correct solution.  If you would like to answer the question I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by @Howdy_McGee who commented on the question.  Using the prepare statement allowed the results to be pulled at the correct time and using %s is for strings and %d would be for a decimal or number value.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM <databaseName>.<tableName> WHERE name = '%s'", get_the_title());
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```